# Convert binary string to hex string and keep its leading zeros

Tags: python, string, binary, hex

May I know how to write a Python script to convert binary string to hexadecimal string and keep the leading zeros?

For an example, I have binary string `"0000000000001010"` and would like to print it into `"000A"`. I know i can use `zfill()` function, but the number of leading zeros is unknown.

Comment: Is it guranteed that the string's length is divisible by 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just divide the number of bits by 4:

```
>>> bits = "0000000000001010"
>>> '{:0{}X}'.format(int(bits, 2), len(bits) // 4)
'000A'
```

Comment: thrilled to see that [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) can take a base!